Concurrent update to one record in same table created a deadlock between primary key and secondary index
Concurrent reqs under odd case has triggered the same update query twice which surprisingly led to deadlock between primary key and secondary index update in the same table. The update query will update more than one indexed columns.
Table schema :
  CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `external_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visitor_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_contacts_on_account_id_and_id` (`account_id`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_contacts_on_account_id_and_external_id` (`account_id`,`external_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_contacts_on_account_id_and_visitor_id` (`account_id`,`visitor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_contacts_on_account_id_and_mobile_number` (`account_id`,`mobile_number`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_contacts_on_account_id_and_twitter` (`account_id`,`twitter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Show engine innodb status (deadlock detection output)
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2024-06-13 09:22:50 22423236462336
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4533358575, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 211488, OS thread handle 22449095415552, query id 178361492 10.213.161.193 mcr updating
update contact set account_id=1725036269708730368, created_at='2024-06-13 09:22:50.611', external_id='7841325875429', mobile_number='+917067794595', status=1, twitter=null, updated_at='2024-06-13 09:22:50.611', visitor_id='f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed79fa9e4' where id=1800015394330326016

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 13086900 n bits 248 index PRIMARY of table `mcr`.`contact` trx id 4533358575 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 181 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 98faf076d94b3400; asc    v K4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00010e358fef; asc    5  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000010a02b20; asc      + ;;
 3: len 8; hex 97f08f5900a76000; asc    Y  ` ;;
 4: len 2; hex 8001; asc   ;;
 5: len 5; hex 99b39a95b3; asc      ;;
 6: len 5; hex 99b39a95b3; asc      ;;
 7: len 13; hex 37383431333235383735343239; asc 7841325875429;;
 8: len 30; hex 66326361376237662d396266332d343036392d663736622d346535656437; asc f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed7; (total 36 bytes);
 9: len 13; hex 2b393137303637373934353935; asc +917067794595;;
 10: SQL NULL;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: SQL NULL;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: SQL NULL;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 10123442 n bits 288 index index_contacts_on_account_id_and_visitor_id of table `mcr`.`contact` trx id 4533358575 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 214 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 97f08f5900a76000; asc    Y  ` ;;
 1: len 30; hex 66326361376237662d396266332d343036392d663736622d346535656437; asc f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed7; (total 36 bytes);
 2: len 8; hex 98fb4c5883870400; asc   LX    ;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 4533358574, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 211486, OS thread handle 22422196635392, query id 178361503 10.213.161.193 mcr updating
update contact set account_id=1725036269708730368, created_at='2024-06-13 09:22:50.61', external_id='7841325875429', mobile_number='+917067794595', status=1, twitter=null, updated_at='2024-06-13 09:22:50.61', visitor_id='f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed79fa9e4' where id=1800015394330326016

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 10123442 n bits 288 index index_contacts_on_account_id_and_visitor_id of table `mcr`.`contact` trx id 4533358574 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 214 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 97f08f5900a76000; asc    Y  ` ;;
 1: len 30; hex 66326361376237662d396266332d343036392d663736622d346535656437; asc f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed7; (total 36 bytes);
 2: len 8; hex 98fb4c5883870400; asc   LX    ;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 26 page no 13086900 n bits 248 index PRIMARY of table `mcr`.`contact` trx id 4533358574 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 181 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 15; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 98faf076d94b3400; asc    v K4 ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00010e358fef; asc    5  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 02000010a02b20; asc      + ;;
 3: len 8; hex 97f08f5900a76000; asc    Y  ` ;;
 4: len 2; hex 8001; asc   ;;
 5: len 5; hex 99b39a95b3; asc      ;;
 6: len 5; hex 99b39a95b3; asc      ;;
 7: len 13; hex 37383431333235383735343239; asc 7841325875429;;
 8: len 30; hex 66326361376237662d396266332d343036392d663736622d346535656437; asc f2ca7b7f-9bf3-4069-f76b-4e5ed7; (total 36 bytes);
 9: len 13; hex 2b393137303637373934353935; asc +917067794595;;
 10: SQL NULL;
 11: SQL NULL;
 12: SQL NULL;
 13: SQL NULL;
 14: SQL NULL;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------

Assumption is if the update query is same, it will acquire lock in same order but it is not the case. Not sure it is bug in mysql.
Edit : Isolation Mode is Repeatable Read.

I guess some converting implicit locks to explicit locks is involved. I'm pretty sure it's Working As Designed™, and there's an explanation in there somewhere

Hmmm. I am not getting why for two concurrent update query on one table the locking order has been changed. And since it is lock within one table, not sure how to resolve this. I think only schema change will resolve this error. Before that need to identify cause of the issue
